# How to escape space as POST parameter?

Tags: php, html

I have a two-parts Persian name: `محمد رضا`

Also I have a HTML form like this:

```
<form class="loginform" action="https://hammihan.com/search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="searcher" value="searcher">
    <input name="name" value="" type="text">
    <input name="family" value="" type="text">
    <select name="marriage">
        <option>جنسیت</option>
        <option value="1">مرد</option>
        <option value="2">زن</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="جستجو">
    <div class="marginbottom"></div>
</form>
```

When I write that Persian name into `name` button and submit the form, I will see the results *(there are some results based on that bane)*. All fine.

---

Now I want to do the same thing by PHP:

```
public function hammihan($request)
{
    $val = "حمید رضا";
    $url = "https://hammihan.com/search.php";
    $data['name'] = $val;
    $data['family'] = "";
    $data['marriage'] = "جنسیت";
    $data['searcher'] = "searcher";

    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);// here we are passing $data
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $res = curl_exec($handle);

    return $res;
}
```

But it returns nothing. I mean that search engine says no result found. Why? Why the exact name will be found when I do send it through a HTML form, and will not be found when I send it through PHP ?

Noted that neither won't work:

```
$val = utf8_encode('حمید رضا');

$val = urlencode('حمید رضا');
```

Also my PHP code works as well for single part names. So the problem is the *space*.

Comment: is it working fine when you send a plain english text ?

Comment: @mrid Yes . . . It works fine for everything except some specific space-contains words.

Comment: did you also try rawurlencode(). See http://php.net/rawurlencode in the examples where someone has a mb_ version of this function (upper example)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the default charset

change it to

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Hope this resolve your problem